# Manipulate Data taken from onclick event in javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm editing somebody's code and I'm stuck with this part. I want to get the data sent through the onclick event. this is the code in the HTML he used a json in this part

```
  <a href="#" title="Reset" onclick='updatePassword(<?= json_encode($employee) ?>)' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resetpassword">Reset Password</a>
```

then in the view source code this what is shown.

```
  <a href="#" title="Reset" onclick='updatePassword({"id":"1"))'>
```

How can I get the id in there to manipulate in my controller namely updatePassword. Pls help.. Thanks in advance :-)

I'm new to this kinds of things btw.

Comment: You just need to handle the data in the format of json. You can interpert/do  whatever you want with it. Maybe you should post the `updatePassword` function.

Comment: all i'm going to do in the updatePassword function is basically to update the password of the user that's why i need the id in there. pls do help

Answer (score 0):

You have to just read and pass the id value or same object to the server request. I dont know what is there in `updatePassword` function but you can implement something like this.

```
function updatePassword (emp) {
  //Here pass emp object to the server request

  $.ajax({
    url: 'controllerUrl',
    data: emp,//Passing the same object {"id":"1"}
    success: function () {
    }
  });
  return false;//to prevent default behavior of anchor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `updatePassword` function can be declared like this

```
function updatePassword (data) {

  $.post({
    'controllerUrl',
    data,//here is {"id":"1"}
    function (data) {
    //get PHP responseText as data and handle it
    }
  });
}
```

and in your control PHP flie (controllerUrl) can just use `$_GET['id']` to get the id, and continue your demand.